# how to exclude rows that have duplicates? (Remove)

Tags: mysql, select

someone can help me execute a query where the duplicate elements of the query are deleted

```
Select * from table where APPNAME = 'Ap1' or APPNAME= 'Ap2'
```

Result using DISTINCT

```
id | APPNAME| USERNAME|
1      Ap1      User1     
2      Ap2      User1    
3      Ap1      User3
4      Ap2      User4
5      Ap1      User5 
6      Ap1      User6 
7      Ap2      User6
```

In this table, user 1 and 6 have both applications. These two users must be removed from the query.

The expected result is

```
id | APPNAME| USERNAME|    
1     Ap1      User3
2     Ap2      User4
3     Ap1      User5
```

---

If I use DISTINCT then it eliminates a duplicate, I need to eliminate them both.

Result using DISTINCT

```
id | APPNAME| USERNAME|
1      Ap1      User1       
2      Ap1      User3
3      Ap2      User4
4      Ap1      User5 
5      Ap2      User6
```

Thanks

Comment: Use group by and then having count(*)=1 with the right where clause

Comment: The `id` column in the expected result set is mildly puzzling — is the ID column in the data not really a part of the table?  You have ID values 1, 2, 3 whereas in the original data the matching ID values are 3, 4, 5.

Comment: Yes, oki, the id is the same. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct * from table where APPNAME = 'Ap1' or APPNAME= 'Ap2' group by APPNAME having (count(APPNAME)=1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this should work, unless there are syntactic issues (most likely the `AS` keyword) that prevent it working in MySQL:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table AS t
 WHERE (t.appname = 'Ap1' OR t.appname = 'Ap2')
   AND t.username NOT IN
       (SELECT u.username
          FROM table AS u
         WHERE (u.appname = 'Ap1' OR u.appname = 'Ap2')
         GROUP BY u.username
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
       )
```

The sub-query lists user names that have more than one entry from the list `Ap1` and `Ap2`, and the NOT IN excludes those from the main query result.  Note that the sub-query applies the same filter on `appname` as the main query to ensure consistency.  Otherwise, you might ignore people who have `Ap1` and `Ap3`, but they should be included because they have only one of `Ap1` and `Ap2`.

This sub-query approach is necessary in most SQL DBMS other than MySQL, and this should work with MySQL too.  There are probably techniques using the OLAP windowing functions too.  However, MySQL also has different rules about what's allowed/required in the select-list and the GROUP BY clauses — standard SQL requires non-aggregate columns appearing in the select-list to be listed in the GROUP BY clause, and most SQL DBMS follow that rule.  As I understand it, MySQL does not, and this may allow alternative (simpler) formulations — but they'll be formulations that don't necessarily work in other DBMS (which may or may not matter to you).

The table aliases (introduced with the `AS` keyword) are not 100% necessary; the query works OK without them (drop the `AS [tu]` clauses, and remove the `t.` and `u.` prefixes).  Testing against another SQL DBMS (Informix 12.10), this works (verbatim — Informix allows the use of most keywords as object names without needing to treat them as delimited identifiers enclosed in double quotes):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table;

CREATE TABLE table
(
    id          INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    appname     VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    username    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table VALUES(1, 'Ap1', 'User1');
INSERT INTO table VALUES(2, 'Ap2', 'User1');
INSERT INTO table VALUES(3, 'Ap1', 'User3');
INSERT INTO table VALUES(4, 'Ap2', 'User4');
INSERT INTO table VALUES(5, 'Ap1', 'User5');
INSERT INTO table VALUES(6, 'Ap1', 'User6');
INSERT INTO table VALUES(7, 'Ap2', 'User6');

SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE (appname = 'Ap1' OR appname = 'Ap2')
   AND username NOT IN
       (SELECT username
          FROM table
         WHERE (appname = 'Ap1' OR appname = 'Ap2')
         GROUP BY username
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
       );
```

The output is:

```
3   Ap1   User3
4   Ap2   User4
5   Ap1   User5
```

Note that I'm treating the `ID` column as a physical column, and hence selecting the values from the original data set.  If it isn't a physical column, don't show it in the question, or do show how it is generated.